# Flutter Charts How do I rotate the X axis?

Tags: charts, flutter

[Example Image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EOz943bpYECaWQvNXLdGA_74EVo2H8Fx) How can I only rotate the x axis on the bar chart?
I used labelRotationAngle to do it with the Kotlin language. Is it possible to do this with Flutter?. Thank you for your help.

[Rotate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXucS.jpg)

```
 charts.BarChart(
   _createDataForChart(key, city_name),
   animate: true,
   behaviors: [new charts.PanAndZoomBehavior()],,
   )
List<charts.Series<priceChart,String>> _createDataForChart(key, city_name){
return [
      new charts.Series<priceChart, String>(
        id: 'Sales',
        colorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault,
        domainFn: (priceChart sales, _) => sales.date,
        measureFn: (priceChart sales, _) => sales.price,
        data: data,
      )
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you done creating it vertically? Only Rotation is left?

Answer (score 5):

U can use the domainAxis with renderSpec to achieve this. Example Code here:

```
charts.BarChart(
  seriesList,
  animate: animate,
  domainAxis: new charts.OrdinalAxisSpec(
    renderSpec: charts.SmallTickRendererSpec(
      //
      // Rotation Here, 
      labelRotation: 45,
    ),
  ),
)
```

45 degree is the best one yet. if u go 90 it will shrink the chart. but you can use  `labelAnchor: charts.TickLabelAnchor.before` with `labelRotation: -90` to achieve what you want. Example code:

```
charts.BarChart(
  seriesList,
  animate: animate,

  domainAxis: new charts.OrdinalAxisSpec(
    renderSpec: charts.SmallTickRendererSpec(
      // Rotation Here,
      labelRotation: -90,
      labelAnchor: charts.TickLabelAnchor.before,

    ),
  ),

)
```